# Error while checking row, after Filtering observational collection

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I'm having trouble with editing an observable collection... I bind columns in codebehind like so...

```
Dim dgCheckBoxColumn As New DataGridCheckBoxColumn()
Dim column_username As New DataGridTextColumn()
Dim textColumn2 As New DataGridTextColumn()
Dim textColumn3 As New DataGridTextColumn()

dgCheckBoxColumn.Header = "Selected"
dgCheckBoxColumn.Binding = New Binding("Selected")
dgvResults.Columns.Add(dgCheckBoxColumn)

column_username.Header = "User Name"
column_username.Binding = New Binding("accountName")
dgvResults.Columns.Add(column_username)

textColumn2.Header = "First Name"
textColumn2.Binding = New System.Windows.Data.Binding("firstName")
dgvResults.Columns.Add(textColumn2)

textColumn3.Header = "Last Name"
textColumn3.Binding = New System.Windows.Data.Binding("lastName")
dgvResults.Columns.Add(textColumn3)
```

Then I create my observablecollection...

```
Dim oc_userlist As New ObservableCollection(Of user)

Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class user

    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Private m_accountname As String
    Private m_firstname As String
    Private m_lastname As String
    Private _Selected As Boolean

    Public Property Selected() As Boolean
        Get
            Return _Selected
        End Get
        Set(value As Boolean)
            _Selected = value
            NotifyPropertyChanged("IsChecked")
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property accountName() As String
        Get
            Return m_accountname
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_accountname = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property firstName() As String
        Get
            Return m_firstname
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_firstname = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property lastName() As String
        Get
            Return m_lastname
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_lastname = value
        End Set
    End Property

#Region "INotifyPropertyChanged Members"

    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler _
        Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

#End Region

#Region "Private Helpers"

    Private Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(propertyName As String)
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
    End Sub

#End Region

End Class
```

Then I add new user to collection, like so...

```
oc_userlist.Add(New user With { _
.Selected = False, _
.accountName = "awiles", _
.firstName = "Anthony", _
.lastName = "Wiles"
})
```

I'm trying to filter using a textbox, with the textchanged event, and it's working wonderfully...

```
Private Sub TextBox_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As TextChangedEventArgs)


        Dim result = oc_userlist.Where(Function(w) w.accountName.Contains(txtFilter.Text.ToString) _
                                           Or w.firstName.Contains(txtFilter.Text.ToString) _
                                           Or w.lastName.Contains(txtFilter.Text.ToString))
        dgvResults.ItemsSource = result

End Sub
```

The problem I'm having is once this is filtered, using the textbox, then I try to select something, it tells me

```
'EditItem' is not allowed for this view.
```

I'm having issues trying to get around this issue, can anybody point me in the correct direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason could be the result of your Linq query (with the Where) is not a List(Of T) but an IEnumerable.

Try adding a call to ToList()

```
Dim result = oc_userlist.Where(Function(w) w.accountName.Contains(txtFilter.Text.ToString) _
   Or w.firstName.Contains(txtFilter.Text.ToString) _
   Or w.lastName.Contains(txtFilter.Text.ToString)) _
   .ToList()
```

Then tell if it works

Comment: This is correct, cannot believe I've spent over 4 hours trying to figure it out!